# how to scan magento on localhost for virus infection?

Tags: magento-1.9, php

We have a Magento Project on local server and we want to upload it to Live server.
But we want to first have a complete scan on our local server for any virus infection.

It is a matter of urgency.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Install antivirus at your system  and scan the  files & folders

Comment: what is your local server OS and live server OS?

Comment: @AmitBera what if a file contains malscript?

Comment: @MagenX Our local server OS is windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually viruses do some activity with local files, so, as option, you can just create a git repo and monitor git status for some time (of course you need to add media etc. folders to git ignore).

As other option, you can download software called [AiBolit](https://www.revisium.com/aibo/). This is bunch of php scripts with most common antivirus templates. This is really good software which help me alot.

Answer (score 3):

**MALDET / LMD**

https://www.rfxn.com/projects/linux-malware-detect/

> Linux Malware Detect (LMD) is a malware scanner for Linux released
>   under the GNU GPLv2 license, that is designed around the threats faced
>   in shared hosted environments.

no matter what you must have this on your server:

```
wget http://www.rfxn.com/downloads/maldetect-current.tar.gz
tar -xvf maldetect-current.tar.gz
cd maldetect-*
./install.sh

maldet -a /path/to/magento/
```

config file for automation and alerts:

```
/usr/local/maldetect/conf.maldet
```